# Swift remove reference to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm adding a view controller programatically via a navigation controller as I need to access the navigation bar whilst the controller is being presented.

I'm currently doing this via the method below however I need to be able to remove the reference to the view controller when the user taps the dismiss button.

```
let settingsController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsController") as! SettingsController
            settingsController.view.alpha = 0
            settingsController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.view.frame.height)
            self.view.addSubview(settingsController.view)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                print(self.view.frame.height)
                settingsController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 142)
                settingsController.view.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)
```

Is there a way I can do this as the current self.dismiss or self.popViewController doesn't work?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I tried to implement this solution using the standard perform segue (below) by presenting modally option as I need to keep the navigation bar active. The settings controller height is less than the view frame. This didn't work so I'm trying the above method.

```
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SettingsSegue", sender: nil)
```

When I call the settings controller up and dismiss another settings controller gets added resulting in multiple settings controllers. This is my issue.

Comment: Hi, Can you paste ScreenShot?

Comment: Not sure what a screenshot would provide in this context as it's code related.

Comment: i don't understand what you need exactly.

Comment: Updated the question :)

Comment: so you want to dismiss settingcontroller?

Comment: Yes - when the user clicks the dismiss button. The problem is that the button is underneath the settings controller (inside the navigation bar). I'm asking the navigation controller to perform the modal segue, however the segue is going above the navigation controller in the hierarchy.

Comment: do one thing add setting controller run and when that button inside naviagtionbar, take one screen shot and show me or any video

Comment: I have given code check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var settingsController : SettingsController!

```
@IBAction func btnNext(_ sender: Any) {
    settingsController  = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsController") as! SettingsController
    settingsController.view.alpha = 1
    settingsController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.view.frame.height)
    self.view.addSubview(settingsController.view)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        print(self.view.frame.height)
        self.settingsController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 142)
        self.settingsController.view.alpha = 1
    }, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func btnDismiss(_ sender: Any) {
        self.settingsController.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: This has solved the issue apart from all the text formatting has gone from the settings controller. I had character spacing on the fonts which are called inside the settings controller viewWillAppear

Comment: Never mind my previous - just placed the spacing code inside view did load and all is well. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: does `self.settingsController` completely removes reference to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Once the variable goes out of scope and the view controller is dismissed it should be de-referenced automatically and garbage collected as Swift uses [ARC (automatic reference counting)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID49)

ARC basically means that Swift will keep track of the instance of that view controller and when it is no longer used it will de-allocate it and mark it for garbage collection.

You shouldn't need to do anything manually. Maybe showing some more of your code will help explain the issue further.

**EDIT:** Whilst the current answer does technically solve your issue. You are adding the ViewControllers view over the current view, the preferred way to do this is to push a view controller onto the navigation stack or segue to another view controller. doing it this way ensures that the view is deallocated when no longer required. With your current solution you are working around the navigation controller rather than using it as intended.

Comment: Hey. The code below is inside a function which gets called when the user taps the settings button. I tried to present this modally as I wanted the navigation bar to stay on top of the settings controller but this wasn't the case. Using this option as a fall back.

Comment: What code are you using to present it? you should be able to present it modally within the navigation controller without any issues.

Comment: Added the initial presentation code to my question. This was my first try at it but the navigation bar was being blocked by the settings controller.

Comment: so you want to present the settings controller full screen and not show the navigation bar? You should 'present' any view controllers in a navigation controller rather than adding it as a subview.

Comment: I want to show the settings controller and still be able to access the navigation bar. Currently the settings controller goes above the navigation bar

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more information. You should seriously consider presenting this view controller rather than adding it as a subview and then shortening the view.

Comment: removeFromSuperView deallocates - https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622421-removefromsuperview

Comment: It just unlinks it from the view and removes any constraints. it doesnt actually deallocate it. thats not the point im trying to make anyway. its standard practice to present or segue to a view controller. doing it this way you can present the view controller from anywhere in your application if you need to. if you wanted to be able to show the settings controller from most top level pages in your application you wouldn't want to do all these coding in every page. just present and dismiss. nice and easy